# jquery ajax post list appends '[]' to querydict in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working on a Django project and I am sending a post request via Jquery's ajax method. The csrftoken has been retrieved from the browsers cookie with javascript.

```
$.ajax({    
    type : 'POST', 
    beforeSend: function( xhr, settings){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken ); 
    },  
    url : '/endpoint/',
    data : { 'requestParam': [1,2,3,4] }
}).done(function(d) {
    callback(d);
});
```

Then I check what the backend receives via the ajax call;

```
print( request.POST )
```

I was expecting this;

```
<QueryDict: {u'requestParam': [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4']}>
```

Instead I get this;

```
<QueryDict: {u'requestParam[]': [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4']}>
```

Which seems odd. Where did the '[]' extra in the key name come from? Is this a convention that is handled this way in Django or is this something that AJAX does when sending lists?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is jQuery believing that everyone in the world uses PHP.

Add `traditional: true` to your `ajax` object.