# Django Form ajax post with checkboxes

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-forms

I am trying to post via AJAX a Django Form with multiple checkboxes selected. When one checkbox is selected, everything works fine. When more than one is selected, it doesn't save anything. I am guessing this happens because of how I am organizing my data in JS before sending to the server.

The model in question is:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(
        choices=((i, i) for i in range(1, 31)),
        default=3)
    taxes = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tax, related_name='room',
        blank=True, limit_choices_to={'hotel': F('hotel')})
```

The form for creating or editing a room is:

```
class RoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)

    class Meta():
        model = Room
        fields = ('name', 'capacity', 'taxes')
        widgets = {
            'capacity': forms.Select,
            'taxes': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
            self.fields['taxes'].queryset = Tax.objects.filter(hotel=kwargs['initial']['hotel'])
```

I post the form via ajax like this:

```
var elements = $('form').serializeArray();
var params = {}, i;
for (i in elements) {
    element = elements[i];
    if (element.name in params) {
        if (!(params[element.name] instanceof Array)) {
            params[element.name] = Array(params[element.name]);
        }
        params[element.name].push(element.value);
    } else {
        params[element.name] = element.value;
    }
}
params['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = CSRF_TOKEN;

$.post(e.target.action, params, function(response) {
    callback(response);
});
```

When one tax checkbox is selected and posted, it works perfectly. However, when more than one tax is selected, django receives the request.POST like this:

```
{..., u'taxes[]': [u'269', u'268', u'156'], ...}
```

Instead of this:

```
{..., u'taxes': [u'269', u'268', u'156'], ...}
```

And so, the form is validated, but no taxes are saved... :(

**Another note:** I have tried jumping in with a breakpoint before posting the form and the params object does not have a `taxes[]` key, but it does correctly have a `taxes` key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many many hours of debugging and searching, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016757/1580632) helped me solve the issue. In a nutshell, in the $.ajax call, just add:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    traditional: true,
    ...
}
```

And that's it.